# How to run single manual test case on multiple browsers without overwriting the test results in ALM?

Tags: hp-alm, manual-testing

I am facing one scenario in which I have set of common test cases that needs to be run on multiple browsers say chrome, IE 10 and IE 11.

These test cases have been mapped to common requirements (No separate requirements for IE/chrome).

How do I run the test cases in test lab without overwriting the test results of any other run?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use test parameters and create separate test configurations for each browser. So you'd do something like this:

1. Add a parameter for "Browser" in your test
2. Insert the parameter in a step such as "Load Firefox", where you are substituting the variable for "Firefox"
3. Add the tests into your test set and set the browser variable accordingly

You can add all the browser scenarios in your test set this way using exactly the same tests, but the test runs will be unique.

The lazier way is just to create a test set for each browser, but the steps wouldn't contain any directions for starting up the correct program.